# Function equation bound between rectangle

Tags: functions

I need to specify the equation form.

I have 4 known points then the equation is:
$$f(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d.$$
I can solve and find $a, b, c, d$.

But also I want this equation to be bound between two known values for a known interval.

Example: I want this function curve to be bound in a rectangle with points
$(4,10)$, $(4,150)$, $(90,10)$, $(90,150)$.

Then what is the formula of equation?

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible solutions for the problem you describe. Here are some of them:

$$a=0, b=0, c=0, d=10\\
a=0, b=0, c=0, d=150\\
a=0, b=0, c=\frac{70}{43}, d=\frac{150}{43}\\
a=0, b=0, c=-\frac{70}{43}, d=\frac{6730}{43}$$

Comment: no. the problem is to to find the formula of the function that passes through 4 points and is bounded inside rectangle

Comment: @Tarek Which four points?

Comment: i have four known points. example: (14,42) (28, 71) (40, 22) (76, 117) so the curve passes through them. Also I want the curve to be bounded inside the rectangle (4,10) (4,150) (90,10) (90,150)

Comment: @Tarek That is impossible. The four points already uniquely determine the third degree polynomial that runs through them. If that polynomial lies in the rectangle or not is not up to your control. Unless, of course, you can actually determine which points you want the polynomial to run through.

Comment: the problem is that i need to determine the nature of this function. i don't know if it is rational or third degree or fourth degree or ...

Comment: may be a trigonometric function or a mix between rational and a quadratic.
What is the equation formula that solve this problem

Comment: @Tarek Then your question is too vague. There are infinitely many functions which satisfy your demands.